# Show title of file metadata in frontend

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.7.x

I have 10 images without a title assigned in filelist module and I have used each of these images 20 times on my website. This will result in 200 sys_file_reference records in database without any title as I have not set a title for each file reference.

Now, I want to optimize my website for SEO. It would be good to add title, alt and description for my images. Instead of editing 200 reference records I just go to filelist and edit this data directly in my 10 images. But TYPO3 still does not render this title.

Currently I have to open each reference record and deactivate the Checkbox "Set element specific value (Default: "MyTitle")", which I have never set.

Do you know an easier way? Is this a TYPO3 bug?

Stefan

I'm using TYPO3 8.7.1. Maybe someone can add this version to stackoverflow tags.

Answer (score 1):

For me it seems that you have to set the title field in the sys_file_reference table to NULL again. This will deactivate the checkbox.

Comment: You mean as database query? Hmm, OK, but not really userfriendly, right?

Comment: As far i know, by default the checkbox for individual the title isnt activated when you add a new picture and the title  is taken from the metadata. I understood you in that way, that already added images have the checkbox checked and you want to fix it. So if you clean your database (title has the default NULL) in the future you wont have to do a query. Just for the old images. But maybe i totally misunderstood you.